# Is there a difference between "addition" and "bitwise addition"?

Tags: c#

As a little project (nothing mission critical), I decided to try and write an implementation of GOST 28147-89 in C#. However, while reading through [RFC 5830](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5830#section-3.2) (an informational defining GOST 28147-89), I noticed this.

> (+)  is a bitwise addition of the words of the same length modulo 2.
>
> [+]  is an addition of 32-bit vectors modulo 2^32.

What is the difference between these two, mainly the first specifying *bitwise* addition, and the second simply stating addition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it says 'modulo 2', I have to assume that they just mean add each bit separately without carry.

So

```
  0101 
 +1111
-------
  1010
```

I can't think of a particularly good use for this, as it's essentially the same as an xor though.

Comment: Would I be fine just using a XOR? Or is there a code snippet which would suit this type of operation better?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do.